# Map data to display 2 attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a problem after I fetch data from the server that looks like this:

> `0:{ Id:1, Firstname:toto, Lastname:cool, } 1:{ Id:1, Firstname:toto, Lastname:cool, } 2:{ Id:2, Firstname:toto, Lastname:cool, }`

And I want to display it on my custom component
`<AutoComplete Label="my list" Data={data} LabelField="Lastname"/>`

For now I only display the last name, but I want to display both the last and first name. They told me I should map data but I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help please?

Comment: can you provide the response data as well as what you want to display?

Comment: The response data is mentioned above id:..., I want to fill the labelField with both the last name and the first name.for now i only display the lastname.thanks

Comment: If this is the case, then you can directly pass the Firstname and Lastname to <Autocomplete /> component. 
Use : <Autocomplete LabelField={responseData["Firstname"]+" "+{responseData["Lastname"]} />

Comment: I edited the data ,i have multiple object.is still the same way?

Comment: @AymenAymen do you want to render out multiple `AutoComplete` components?

Comment: Just one Autocomplete component that displays multipe first and last name of people

Comment: Ok. I will edit the answer

Comment: if you have multiple objects then you have to use .map

Comment: Are you sure that it is the correct data you are getting from the server? It is not an array for sure. It seems like an object but there are no any commas ( , ) after main the key value pairs

Comment: Thank you for you time rifky, i tried lajos solution and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mapping data

If the object is unique:

```
data.Compositename = `${data.Firstname} ${data.Lastname}`;
```

If you have an array of objects as data, then:

```
data = data.map((item) => {Id: item.Id, Firstname: item.Firstname, Lastname: item.Lastname, Compositename: `${item.Firstname} ${item.Lastname}`});
```

and then use:

```
<AutoComplete Label="my list" Data={data} LabelField="Compositename"/>
```

## Preparing on the server

Alternatively you could modify the server-side API (if you have access and are allowed to do so) so that it would return the format of

```
{ Id:1, Firstname:"toto", Lastname:"cool", Compositename: "toto cool"}
```

and, again, use `Compositename` as the value for `LabelField`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```js
data.map(element => ({Firstname: element.Firstname, Lastname: element.Lastname});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.how can i put it in the labelGield after doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.